# Template expression doesnt allow Callexpression in for loop

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

I have below code,

```
<template>
        <td>
            <template for:each={data} for:item="row" for:index="idx">
                <template lwc:if={isEmpty(row[0])}>
                    {row[1]}
                </template>
            </template>
<template if:true={isLast(idx, data.length)}><span>End</span>
</template>
        </td>
</template>
```

```
isEmpty(value){
return !value || value == '';
}

isLast(index, length){
return index == length -1;
}
```

Also tried getter but it stated should not pass parameter. How to check whether the array first value is empty or not. Looked at other posts but did not understood their solution clearly. Not sure how to fix this template expression does not allow Callexpression issue.
Also the data we are using on the html and js is child component so we are passing only array value to child. And the child is custom type in datatable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't use the idx variable outside of the loop. Whatever it is you're trying to do, you're going about it the wrong way. You should explain the reason why you are doing this. See the [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: The requirement is we need to get class teacher info for each student with their id as it will be broken into array like row[0] as id and row[1] as name so we populate name of the teacher as link and if user clicks on it we need to open teacher record and also there will be a case where there might be multiple teachers for a specific student so we need to check whether it is the last in the array or not so we need to use isLast function to figure it out.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but your first response is right solution for first scenario and forgot to add second scenario in the questionnaire later realized it and added the specific code.